# AJAX Return for non obtrusive page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form with an id or 'display'. It has one value to send which is a select item that I gave an id of 'services' to.

I want to send the value of 'services' to a function I have created in a seperate php page. The page is called 'functs.php' and the function name is called 'searchResults'.

The 'searchResults' function works, this much I know. It queries a database and outputs 8 seperate php echo statements. I have ran the PHP function and know it works. I know the issues is with my javascript because, well, I am not the greatest at JavaScript and usually shy away from it.

As of right now, the code is not doing anything. My form has its own action to post to a seperate php page.

```
<form id="display" action="resultPage.php" method="POST">
```

I am trying to use the javascript/ajax to instantly update the contents of a div BUT if the user has jscript turned off, I want the form to ppost to the alternate page. Here is my jscript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#display').submit(function(e) {
var formData = $('#services');

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: functs.php,
        data: '$formData',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.success)
            {
        $.amwnd({
        title: 'Error!',
        content: data.message,
        buttons: ['ok'],
    closer: 'ok'
    });
    }
}
});

e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
});
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

function searchResults()
{

 require 'db_config.php';

   $sql= "SQL CODE HERE"

$theStyle = <<<HERE
"height:100%;
width:70%;
margin:4% AUTO 0;
padding:1.75em;
font-size:1.25em;
border-radius:5em;
color:white;
background-color:#b72027;
;"
HERE;



   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo ("<div style = $theStyle>");
    echo ("<table>");
    echo ("<tr><td>" . $row["0"] . "</td></tr>");
    echo ("<tr><td>" . $row["1"] . "</td>");
       echo ("<tr><td>" . $row["2"] . ", " . $row["3"] . " " . $row["4"] . "</td></tr>");
       echo ("<tr><td>Phone: " . $row["5"] . "</td></tr>");
       echo ("<tr><td>"  .  "<a href=\"http://" . $row["6"] . "\">" . $row["6"] . "</a>"  .     "</td></tr>");
       echo ("<tr><td>" . $row["8"] . " " . $row["9"] . ", " . $row["10"] . "</td></tr>");
    echo ("<tr><td>" . $row["11"] . "</td></tr>");
       echo ("<tr><td></td></tr>");
       echo ("<tr><td></td></tr>");
       echo ("<tr><td>" . $row["7"] . "</td></tr>");
    echo ("</table>");
    echo ("</div>");
       echo ("<br />");

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Does the `select` element have a `name` attribute? If you only have the ID defined, it won't be sent to the server. Needs a name.

Comment: it has a name and a id of 'services'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code has a couple of issues. The PHP script name needs to be a string inside of quotation marks, and the formData variable has an unnecessary "$." Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#display').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = $('#display').serialize();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'functs.php',
        data: formData,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.success)
            {
        $.amwnd({
        title: 'Error!',
        content: data.message,
        buttons: ['ok'],
    closer: 'ok'
    });
    }
}
});

});
});
```

Comment: Just updated to serialize the form before sending. Didn't notice that missing from the first time. Try it out now.

Comment: I think we'd have to see the HTML then, because `e.preventDefault()` stops the form submission, or at least it should.

Comment: Actually, try it now. I had the IDs for your form and select mixed up. Sorry about that. Edit: Well, you did actually :)

Comment: If you answer this question I might be able to make it work... the page I am posting to in the AJAX is a php page with 3 different functions on it. When I submit, I send the services to the php page BUT how do I send it to call a specific function on THAT page?

Comment: We'd need to see the PHP code. The form data is being sent to your server, so we need to see the PHP code to know how it's being handled.

Comment: It works!! I got it to work now. I had to fix my php page by adding the $_POST line.